# Why doesn't jackson save types?

Tags: json, java-8, jackson

I am trying to have jackson save types along with values, as follows:

```
@Test
public void doesNotSaveNestedTypes() throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    mapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT, JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_ARRAY);
    mapper.registerSubtypes(MyResultList.class, MyResult.class);
    String json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(getMyResultList());
    System.out.println(json);
}

private MyResultList getMyResultList(){
    List<MyResult> myList = new ArrayList<>(3);
    myList.add(new MyResult(1));
    myList.add(new MyResult(2));
    return new MyResultList(myList);
}
```

The types are not in the generated json:

```
{
  "myResults" : [ {
    "r" : 1
  }, {
    "r" : 2
  } ]
}
```

Here are the classes involved in this example:

```
public class MyResult {
    private int r;
    public MyResult(){}
    public MyResult(int r){this.r = r;}

    public int getR() {
        return r;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyResult{" +
                "r=" + r +
                '}';
    }
}

import lombok.*;

import java.util.List;

@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class MyResultList {
    @NonNull
    private final List<MyResult> myResults;
}
```

Based on documentation, I was expecting to get the following:

```
{
  ["org.mypackage.MyResultList", {"myResults":  [ 
["org.mypackage.MyResults", {
    "r" : 1
  }, 
     (snip)
```

I have tried removing lombok attributes - that does not help at all.
How to make jackson save types?

Comment: Please add expected output

Comment: @msfoster expected output added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `JAVA_LANG_OBJECT`. You need `NON_FINAL` in your case. Here is the description of these options from the [docs](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization):

- `JAVA_LANG_OBJECT`: only affects properties of type Object.class
- `OBJECT_AND_NON_CONCRETE`: affects Object.class and all non-concrete types (abstract classes, interfaces)
- `NON_CONCRETE_AND_ARRAYS`: same as above, and all array types of the same (direct elements are non-concrete types or Object.class)
- `NON_FINAL`: affects all types that are not declared 'final', and array types of non-final element types.

Using `NON_FINAL` will result in this output:

```
[ "org.mypackage.MyResultList", {
  "myResults" : [ "java.util.ArrayList", [ [ "org.mypackage.MyResult", {
    "r" : 1
  } ], [ "JacksonBinding.MyResult", {
    "r" : 2
  } ] ] ]
} ]
```

Couldn't see a way to avoid having `"java.util.ArrayList"` in the output without annotations.

Comment: It is actually useful to have "java.util.ArrayList", so this works